# "[Errno 2] No such file or directory" when trying to backup a database in pgAdmin4

Tags: pgadmin-4

I have finally managed to get around managing to manually set "PostgreSQL Binary Path" in preferences (why should the user have to do this when it wasn't necessary in pgAdmin3?).

Though to be honest, I have no idea what is meant with the second path field called "EDB Advanced Server Binary Path". But I get no more error message concerning that so I assume it is o.k. to leave that empty.

Now I am stuck on the next step.

When trying to backup the database I have to enter a filename. No matter what I do here, I keep getting this error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Well, it can not be that I have to create a file *before* it is created by pgAdmin, can it?

What could I be doing wrong?

Alex

---

update: answering to @n33rma here are the print screens:

[image: path setting with corrected path]
[image: backup setting]
[image: backup failing]

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem through the command line.

If we use a previous format, it has the same response as you had:

```
$ pg_restore -d <DBNAME> --username=postgres g=<FILENAME> 
pg_restore: [archiver] could not open input file "g=<FILENAME>": No such file or directory
```

If we change the last param, it works properly:

```
$ pg_restore -d <DBNAME> --username=postgres <FILENAME>
```

I suppose the GUI-command changed in v4, but the console pg_restore is not.

Answer (score 3):

I just updated to pgAdmin v4.1 and this solved the issue :-)
Thanks all for helping!

Comment: But, how to upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

You need to give absolute path with the file name to sql file like below.

Windows

C:/test/test.sql

Linux

/u01/test.sql

Answer (score 0):

Enter only a filename, no path, because pgadmin puts the backup in its own directory, specifically, in ~/.pgadmin/storage/(user).

Comment: Yesterday this always gave me the "[Errno 2] No such file or directory" error. Today I get no feedback - only the window closes. And I cant find any backup file. ~/.pgadmin folder seems not to exist

Comment: to be honest: I am not exactly awed by the user experience of pgAdmin4 vs pgAdmin3 so far :-(

Comment: I then tried to restore using pgAdmin4. Result: "[Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Comment: Seems like pgAdmin4 is extremely buggy. And pgAdmin III still does the job, even though it warns you that PostgreSQL v9.6 is not supported

Comment: Searched for the place to see and create issues. Found it (not on Github). Had to create a login. Which then failed. So I cant even see the existing issues now... :-(

Comment: Of course google will not be able to find the issues either as they are hidden behind a login so basically this is a black box for pgAdmin users :-(

Comment: Tried resetting the password for postgresql.org and recreating it. Again login fails. Giving up now :-(

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that path for "PostgreSQL Binary Path" is not set properly in pgAdmin4.

pgAdmin4 is Web application and pgAdmin3 is Desktop application, So pgAdmin4 needs to know path of utilities like `pg_dump` & `pg_restore` binaries so that it can execute them.

In pgAdmin4 Goto: `File > Preferences > Paths > Binary paths > PostgreSQL Binary Path`

If you are using Windows than provide path like,
**C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin**

If you are using Linux than provide path like,
**/opt/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin**

```
user@mint:/opt/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin$ lsh pg_du* pg_res*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xxx xxx 150K Sep  2  2015 pg_restore
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xxx xxx  49K Sep  2  2015 pg_resetxlog
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xxx xxx  83K Sep  2  2015 pg_dumpall
-rwxr-xr-x 1 xxx xxx 364K Sep  2  2015 pg_dump
```

Comment: I am trying this on my mac notebook: here the path seems to be "Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin". But this does not work

Comment: Also: When backing up I can use a file chooser. No matter where I choose to create the backup file, I get the mentioned error message

Comment: You need to provide path as "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin"

Added '/' before Library & try again.

And if issue still persists than could you provide screenshot of error?

Comment: Done. Please see updated question. I had tried this path before - does not work either.

Comment: i am having the same issue and cannot seem to find resolutions of this. @Alex, were you able to find resolution for this issue?

Comment: @Sky21.86: besides using pgAdmin III - no

Comment: That was my solution as well. I did get it to work on pgadmin4 on Windows tho. did all the same steps and is simply just worked. so I guess osx installation either has a bug, or requires some specific setup.

Comment: @Alex Do you have permission to access "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin" to your login user? Please confirm that and if not then provide required permission & try again. I am using the same configuration in pgAdmin4 in my mac & I am able to run Backup/Restore without any issue. are you using pgAdmin4 bundled in Postgres9.6 setup or separate setup taken from pgadmin.org?

Comment: @Alex  Also make sure that you use **File Manager to create/select file** in pgAdmin4. Click the ellipsis[...] button to open File Manager.

Comment: I have reading permissions in the "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin" folder. Set to writing - does not help

Comment: Yes, pgAdmin 4 kind of works on Windows for me: It creates the backup file :-) but then never ends backing up and the file size remains at 0KB :-(

Comment: So I am forced to use pgAdmin III on Windows too

Answer (score 0):

In my case Windows 11 Security blocked it.

Go to "Controled Folder Access" -> Protection History and search for the entry that wants to write in your folder.

Allow it to access the folder.
Maybe you need to do it twice, as in my case there were two processes writing to the disk.

Answer (score -1):

On MacOS 10.11 and using postgres.app I resolved it this way:

[image]

Comment: i used this path: `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin` on Sierra