# restore database PgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, pg-restore, pgadmin-4

i am trying to restore database in PgAdmin 4 and getting an error 
"[Errno 2] No such file or directory" with i assume is related to the the backup file, which is located in /Users/myuser/Downloads/dbupload (PostgreSQL installed on my local machine). This makes me believe that the issue is not with the file but with the link to the file.

In pgadmin 3 all is working ok and given that pgadmin was related a few weeks ago, i am not getting much support online.

Any assistance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is already answered: ["[Errno 2] No such file or directory" when trying to backup a database in pgAdmin4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39796268/errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-when-trying-to-backup-a-database-in-pgadmi)

And make sure you use pgAdmin4 file manager to locate your file & once your file is selected using file manager, it displays properly in Filename filed
**/Users/myuser/Downloads/dbupload/< your_selected_restore_file >**

if you see **/Users/myuser/Downloads/dbupload/** means your file is not selected properly.

Answer (score 0):

So, you have to go to OTHER LOCATIONS, then:
var/lib/pgadmin/storage/postgres_localhost
There, I created a folder called Backup and put all the backup files from the Databases.

Remember that you need to access these locations as Root.
You can do that either by installing Nautilus, then clicking with the right-button on the folder and Open as Administrator (you will be requested your password of course).