# Error When Restoring Database in Pgadmin4

Tags: python, database, postgresql, restore

I'm trying to restore database to pgadmin4 in Ubuntu, but when i select the database and click 'restore', error happen. The error say:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python': 'python'
```

Some body can help me to resolve this error please. Thank you.

Comment: Have you reviewed this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39796268/errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-when-trying-to-backup-a-database-in-pgadmi/40308347#40308347

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["\[Errno 2\] No such file or directory" when trying to backup a database in pgAdmin4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39796268/errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-when-trying-to-backup-a-database-in-pgadmi)

Comment: yes,  I have tried it and still error.

Comment: The question is not duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `python` on the pgadmin server - it resolve problem